# Laravel 5.7 Auth + React. How to combine them?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

Started on learning Laravel and React and I wanted to combine what I did so far with Laravel and it's authentication system and React.

The problem is, I don't know how to implement `Auth::routes()` with React App. The case is I have had my Laravel do the auth files -> (Laravel 5.7)

```
php artisan make:auth
```

This comes with default login, register and recovering password via email modules, that satisfy my needs. But, I wanted to implement it in React, as I'm total noob, I'm here to ask, how do I translate these:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function(){
    Route::resource('tasks', 'TaskController', [
        'only'=>[
            'index', 'store', 'update'
        ]
    ]);
});
```

to my React App.js main file:

```
const App = () => {
    return(
        <Router className="App__container">
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/">
                    <Home />
                </Route>
                <Route path='/login'>
                    <Login /> 
                </Route>
                <Route></Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
};
```

I've found what are the specific routes added by `Auth::routes();` but I don't know how to translate them into React. Any leads I can take? Or is it even possible? Maybe the default Laravel's auth model won't fit here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use default Laravel's auth in case if you use API request. The default authentication is possible if you use API routes. So what you have to do is to instead of returning the view on the login route return view for the application. In other cases, you can use SSR using next.js with Laravel which a headache to attach.
I would highly recommend you to go for 1st approach as you have to use API authentication you will get the token store in the cookie next time use it in the Request header as Authorization.
use api.php for routes don't forget to define the version of your application while doing this.

```
Route::prefix('v1')->group(function () {
   Route::group(['namespace' => 'API\UserAccess'], function () {
      Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
   });
});
```

To serve view where you will load all your react code define in web.php.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('main');
});
```

where in main.blade.php.

```
<div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{mix('js/Main/Main.js')}}"></script>
```

Don't forget to use webpack mix along for this.
Thanks